# Convert table to variable

Tags: sas

I would like to convert a table of 1x1:

```
max
5
```

into a variable to do a for loop and searching on the internet I have not found anything.

To create a variable from a table (1x1):

```
proc sql noprint;
    select max into :macro_make
        from table;
quit;
%put &macro_make.;
```

And then do the loop to repeat a table n times:

```
data want;
    set have;
run;

%macro append(n);
    %do i = 1 %to (&n-1);
        Proc append base=want data=have;
        run;
    %end;
%mend append;

%append(&macro_make);
```

You know how can I deal with this?

Comment: use **call symput** in the datastep or **select into** in the PROC SQL to get a value into macrovariable, then you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I asked the question very soon because I have for want I wanted to do, so here it is. Just in case some want it in the future:

To create a variable from a table (1x1):

```
proc sql noprint;
    select max into :macro_make
        from table;
quit;
%put &macro_make.;
```

And then do the loop to repeat a table n times:

```
data want;
    set have;
run;

%macro append(n);
    %do i = 1 %to (&n-1);
        Proc append base=want data=have;
        run;
    %end;
%mend append;

%append(&macro_make);
```